# How do I prove $BE:EQ=3:1$?

Tags: geometry

If $AD$ is median of $△ABC$, $E$ is the midpoint of median. When $BE$ is produced it cuts $AC$ at point $Q$. Prove that $BE:EQ=3:1$.

[image]

Comment: https://www.nextgurukul.in/nganswers/ask-question/answer/AD-is-a-median-of-triangle-ABC-and-E-is-the-midpoint-of-AD/Quadrilaterals/29035.htm

Comment: Using [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) twice.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $DC$. Then $EM \parallel AC$ because $E$ is the midpoint of $AD$. It follows that
$$BE:EQ = BM:MC = 3:1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be midpoint of $QC$ and $EQ=x$.

Thus, since $DN||EQ$, we obtain:
$$DN=2x,$$
$$BQ=4x$$, $$BE=3x$$ and we are done!